# commitEditingStyle makes my app crash

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My app has crashed multiple times while implementing a swipe to delete feature.

```
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
 (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section 
before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or     
deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the 
number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved    
out).'
```

I read somewhere that this has to do with rows not being decremented by 1 at `numberOfRowsInSection` so I created a `var deleted :Bool?` to  change whenever a data / row is deleted. Now, I just swipe and delete once and my app crashes after another attempt.

> Here are the codes related to this:

```
var myFavs : [MyFavourites]?

var deleted :Bool?



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if deleted == true {

        return myFavs!.count - 1
    } else {
        return (myFavs?.count)!
    }
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        //Delete from CD.

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


        let myFavo = myFavs![indexPath.row]

        context.deleteObject(myFavo as MyFavourites)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch _ {
        }


        // Delete the row from the data source

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        deleted = true

        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }    
}
```

**[Edit]**

My Data source `var myFavs : [MyFavourites]?` is a generated NSManagedObject subclass from CoreData. I forgot to mention that it deletes successfully from coreData when I restart the App from Simulator.

Here's my Data Source code if necessary.

```
extension MyFavourites {

@NSManaged var id: String?

}
```

> What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you are using myFavs as your data source, you need to keep it updated for changes. For example, when you make deletions, you need to remove the corresponding item from myFavs. Use a delete Bool is not needed and won't help either. Probably you should post more data source delegate methods.

Comment: You need to update `myFavs`. e. g. delete myFavo in this case

Comment: If you read the error message, it tells you what your doing wrong. It states, `The number of rows contained in a section after the update needs to match the number of rows before the update plus or minus the number of updates` So in other words, your `numberOfRowsInSection` count needs to always equal it's data source after any changes to the data source. So if you delete a row, you have to update the dataSource so `numberOfRowsInSection` equals it's return (data source). [You don't need a bool for this], simply update your array

Comment: `What am I doing wrong ?` The error message is describing that perfectly.. Make sure your `dataSource` was updated as well..

Comment: @JoeSmith I just updated post.

Comment: @anhtu I think I already have that done here `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` and it's in the code I posted. I have edited post with dataSource structure.

Comment: Can you print `myFavs.count` after this line `context.deleteObject(myFavo as MyFavourites)`. And in `numberOfRowsInSection`, I think you are doing wrong, just need myFavs.count.

Comment: Thanks for the response @soulshined. Please follow up ^

Comment: @0yeoj Thanks for the response. Please follow up. Thanks.

Comment: @youngbobby, you probably miss to update your dataSource :: somthing like this `self.arrayOfData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)`

Comment: @0yeoj Thank you! :-)